# How to disable url rewrite building for disabled store view? Magento

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.9

I want to disable url rewrites for a specific disabled store.

In Magento "Configuration > Web" I set "Use Web Server Rewrites" to "No", but Magento still generates new urls in "URL Rewrites Management".

Does anybody know how to prevent Magento from building new urls for a disabled store view?

Comment: while selecting Configuration > Web did you select correct store & cleared cache ?

Comment: Yes. The disabled store view is set to "No" at "Use Web Server Rewrites". URL rewrite management still add urls.

Comment: Please try clearing cache and run indexing specially url rewrite.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work. Magento still generates url rewrites for disabled store view...